# sending std::endl to stream gives memory address

Tags: c++, stream, endl

Can somebody explain to me why this program sends an address to std::cout?

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>


std::ostream& stuff(std::ostream& o, std::string s)
{
    o << s << std::endl;
    return o;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << stuff(std::cout, "word") << std::endl;

}
```

It is caused by the std::endl in main().. but why??

output:

```
word
0x804a064
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `stuff` returns the `std::ostream` that was passed into it.

That means your code:

```
std::cout << stuff(std::cout, "word") << std::endl;
```

Will actually call:

```
std::cout << (std::cout) << std::endl;
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the result of calling "stuff"
```

You are outputting the address of your `std::cout` object.

Your program is functionally equivalent to:

```
std::cout << "word" << std::endl;
std::cout << std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: why does the ouput change when removing endl in main()? The address will disappear then.

Comment: @lotolmencre that's not described anywhere in your question.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.  Good luck!

Comment: Huh? It is. In my question I wrote "It is caused by the std::endl in main()". Meaning, that behaviour only appears when the endl is present in main().

Comment: @lotolmencre FYI, compiling with gcc 4.9.2 prints the address with and without using `std::endl` in the `main` function.

Comment: @lotolmencre then you're asking about behavior that you haven't described.  I don't want to guess how your program behaves without the `std::endl`.  Why do you want us to guess?

Comment: @lotolmencre Try `std::cout << std::cout << std::endl;` and you should see you get the same exact address. Why removing `std::endl` from the `main` function changes the behavior is a different issue.

Comment: What then is the proper way to do this? Because std::ostream& operatpr<<() didn't display this behavior whenever I implemented it. What is different about this?

Comment: nvm, I think I figured it out. operator<< takes the stream on teh left as a parameter and writes to it. stuff() writes also to the parameter stream but then sends that streams address to itself.

Thanks guys.